# How to display strings in X / Y labels with dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am totally new to dc.js and I need help with displaying the following json as a [2-dimensional heatmap](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html):

```
var dataJson = [
                {'X': 'category1', 'Y': 'category1', 'Value': 850},
                {'X': 'category1', 'Y': 'category2', 'Value': 550},
                {'X': 'category1', 'Y': 'category3', 'Value': 900},
                {'X': 'category1', 'Y': 'category4', 'Value': 900},
                {'X': 'category2', 'Y': 'category1', 'Value': 550},
                {'X': 'category2', 'Y': 'category2', 'Value': 650},
                {'X': 'category2', 'Y': 'category3', 'Value': 300},
                {'X': 'category2', 'Y': 'category4', 'Value': 600},
                .......];
```

I am trying to use the following code to draw the heatmap:

```
        var chart = dc.heatMap("#test");
        var ndx = crossfilter(dataJson),
            runDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                return [+d.Y, +d.X];
            }),
            runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
                return +d.Value;
            });
        chart
            .width(45 * 4 + 80)
            .height(45 * 4 + 40)
            .group(runGroup)
            .keyAccessor(function (d) {
                return +d.key[0];
            })
            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                return +d.key[1];
            })
            .colorAccessor(function (d) {
                return +d.value;
            })
            .title(function (d) {
                return 'Y:   ' + d.key[0] + '\n' +
                    'X:  ' + d.key[1] + '\n' +
                    'Value: ' + (d.value);
            })
            .colors(['#ffffd9', '#edf8b1', '#c7e9b4', '#7fcdbb', '#41b6c4', '#1d91c0', '#225ea8', '#253494', '#081d58'])
            .calculateColorDomain();
        chart.render();
```

The code works when the values are numbers but not when strings.

My Q is - what should I add in order to make it work with strings as values (I get a black square) and also display the strings on each x/y tick?

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed by removing '+' from the code above:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(dataJson),
                runDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
                    return [d.Y, d.X];
                }),
                runGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
                    return d.Value;
                });
            chart
                .width(45 * 4 + 80)
                .height(45 * 4 + 40)
                .group(runGroup)
                .keyAccessor(function (d) {
                    return d.key[0];
                })
                .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                    return d.key[1];
                })
                .colorAccessor(function (d) {
                    return d.value;
                })
                .title(function (d) {
                    return 'Y:   ' + d.key[0] + '\n' +
                        'X:  ' + d.key[1] + '\n' +
                        'Value: ' + (d.value);
                })
                .colors(['#ffffd9', '#edf8b1', '#c7e9b4', '#7fcdbb', '#41b6c4', '#1d91c0', '#225ea8', '#253494', '#081d58'])
                .calculateColorDomain();
            chart.render();
```